# Get results from mySQL database based on timestamp and other criteria in multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, search, checkbox

I have a database with only a few tables that is populated based on values submitted through ever changing form content that contain a lot of checkboxes, radio, select list variables, etc...

Each element of the form has a unique ID attached such as Q1, Q2, Q3, etc...  Whatever the user checks off on the information is then added to the database.

The "submission" table that the information gets inserted into looks like this:

```
doc_id  ques   ans          other   final  
1       Q1     1            blah    1
1       Q2     5                    1
1       Q2     6                    1
3       Q3     1            blah   
4       Q4     8
1       Q6     1375228800           1
```

If a user wants to get all documents with Q1 set as 1 and Q2 set as 5, it works, but when a date is specified is where it doesn't work.

The search criteria can change on the fly, and it's mostly working except when trying to filter results by timestamp, like the "ans" field showing the Unix timestamp of '1375228800'

Here's an example:

```
SELECT doc_id FROM submission
WHERE (ques IN ('Q1') AND ans IN ('1'))
AND (ques IN ('Q2') AND ans IN ('5'))
AND (ques = 'Q6' AND ans >= '0' AND ans <= '1375228800')
AND final = '1' 
GROUP BY doc_id
```

It works except when adding the timestamp portion... in this case Q6 has a value of 1375228800.

What would be the best way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things with your query that need modification.

First off, if you are comparing against a single value, there is no reason to use the IN clause.  So change your

```
ques IN ('Q1')
```

to

```
ques = 'Q1'
```

and the same for similar instances.

Secondly, I presume you are storing your timestamps as integers, and not as strings.  Therefore, you should not be surrounding the timestamps in quotes, which denote a string comparison.  Instead, you can simply write,

```
ans >= 0 AND ans <= 1375228800
```

Or you can use the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator

```
ans BETWEEN 0 and 1375228800
```

Finally, you are confusing the English understanding of "AND" with the programmatic understanding.  If you say,

```
(ques IN ('Q1') AND ans IN ('1'))
AND (ques IN ('Q2') AND ans IN ('5'))
```

You are requiring that ques is both Q1 and Q2 at the same time, a clear impossibility.  Instead, you want to be using the "OR" clause.  Given this, your query can be re-written as

```
SELECT doc_id FROM submission
WHERE ((ques = 'Q1' AND ans = 1)
    OR (ques = 'Q2' AND ans = '5')
    OR (ques = 'Q6' AND ans BETWEEN 0 AND 1375228800))
    AND final = 1 
GROUP BY doc_id
```

This will select all submissions where:

- The question is Q1, the answer is 1, and final is 1
- The question is Q2, the answer is 5, and final is 1
- The question is Q6, the answer is between 0 and 1375228800, and final is 1

Comment: I see what you're saying, but maybe I need to clarify what the query is doing, since this approach still won't work.  All of the "questions" can have multiple entries in the table.  For example, on submission if a user checked "1", "2", and "6" for Q1 on document 2, then Q1 will be added three times to the database.  Now if someone searches for a document that contains "2" and "6" with a time less than 1375228800 in the Q6 field, then document 2 should be found